# Is it secure to install both Nginx and Shoutcast on one server

Tags: nginx, streaming

I want to use one server as a host (Nginx) and a streaming server.
Is it secure to install both Nginx and Shoutcast on one server?

Comment: Questions on Server Fault must be about managing information technology systems in a business environment. Home and end-user computing questions may be asked on Super User. However, using a container could always be a condition. Security depends on opinions, soft and hware configuration so it's not easy to tell but due opinion based answers, also offtopic

Comment: Secure against what? What is your risk model?

Comment: @EsaJokinen Is it ok to install both of them on one server in the real world?

Comment: Why wouldn't it be? Shoutcast doesn't support TLS, so it's pretty common to use Nginx in front of Shoutcast as a *reverse proxy* that can provide TLS, web application firewall, etc.

Comment: @EsaJokinen Thanks a lot for your answer. will you please tell me where can I find a tutorial to connect Shoutcast and an Nginx server block? I've installed Shoutcast and I have a domain for it. but I don't know how to connect an Nginx server block to use it as a domain instead of using server IP to access Shoutcast. I'm searching for 2 days and didn't get an answer.

Comment: Bind Shoutcast on localhost and use Nginx as a *reverse proxy*.